# C# Find specific string/text in ListBox Items and select it ALL

Tags: c#, listbox, contains, items, selectedvalue

How can I select all the Items + the Item above the line I got found in my ListBox? For example...
I have a ListBox with more than 200 Items:

- Listbox with Items:
- 23 * - T41 EMK-D40, 62H7 BOHRFRAESEN, A0, C0
- 24 CALL PGM \744
- 25 TOOL CALL 41 Z S1600 F1000
- 26 CALL LBL 500
- 27 CYCL DEF 208 BOHRFRAESEN ~
- Q200=+2    ;SICHERHEITS-ABST. ~
- Q201=-55   ;TIEFE ~
- Q206= AUTO ;VORSCHUB TIEFENZ. ~
- Q334=+1    ;ZUSTELL-TIEFE ~
- Q203=+0    ;KOOR. OBERFLAECHE ~
- Q204=+50   ;2. SICHERHEITS-ABST. ~
- Q335=+61   ;SOLL-DURCHMESSER ~
- Q342=+39   ;VORGEB. DURCHMESSER ~
- Q351=+1    ;FRAESART
- 28 L  Z+150 R0 FMAX
- 29 L  X+1138  Y-915 R0 FMAX
- 30 L  Z+22 R0 FMAX
- 31 L M8 M3
- 32 CALL LBL 14
- 33 L  Z+150 R0 FMAX M9 M5
- 34 L  Y+1200  Z+1200 R0 FMAX M92
- 35 STOP

I want to search for the string/text "M8 M3" and select all the Items + the Item above it (= line 30 + 31).
In my case, unfortunately, only one item is selected. However, all items should be selected + the item above it. I hope someone can help. Thanks.

I try this code:

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var content in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (content.ToString().Contains("M8 M3"))
                {
                    listBox1.SelectedItem = content;
                    and select item above it...
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you select all the items - is not the item above the found item already selected? What do you mean?

Comment: I want select the Item I search for (in my case line 31) and the line 30 (the line above the Item I search for.) So both must be selected at the end.

Comment: Put your ListBox into MultiSelect Mode. Use a simple for loop so you get an actual index to work with instead of a foreach. Instead of using SelectedItem (thats just for single selection) call `SetSelected(index, true)` on the index you get from the for loop and on index-1 when index is greater then 0.

Comment: Could you please write an example? Have low skill in C#. THX.

Comment: try removing `break` inside the `foreach` loop

Comment: If I removing break, an error pupup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop. If you match at index i, you can acccess i-1 for the previous element. However, consider what is supposed to happen if it is the first element that matches. (There is no previous element to grab)

Comment: Could you please write an example?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++){
  //if blabla select listBox1.Items[i] and lisBox1.Items[i-1]
}

Comment: Nothing happens. don't work.